# Ceiling fan with light and 2 wall switches

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I'm replacing ceiling fan with light. My problem is the wiring in ceiling. There are 6 black wires. (I've not had fixture in long time.) There are red, white, brown in addition to black. I have 2 wall switches. In ceiling fan there is black, white, green,  blue. I need help figuring colors together. I think black wires need to be separated somehow. Help!

Comment: Any pictures of before you undid all the wires(please say yes)?  Edit any pictures into your question.  Pictures of how switches are wire will help also.

Comment: Wires in ceiling should have more colours(at least white).  Black colour should only be use for hot/live wires, white for neutral, and green/bare for ground(metal conduit(tubes) also for ground).  Do you own or rent?  Renters not allowed to do electric work.

Comment: @crip659  Keep in mind that there are probably switch loops here and in the ceiling white wires would be connected to always hot and would be marked with usually black tape.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Without pictures of the current wiring and an indication of where in the world you live, it will be _very_ difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Don't change stuff that isn't already connected to the fan... a lot of novices see stuff they don't understand and assume the other guy made a mistake... that's not the way to bet when you're new to it.